# Dynamic C# with security preventing database access

Tags: .net, security, appdomain

In short, I would to create a user-managed set up razor templates for e-mails, allowing end-users to use the power of .net/razor to create awesome e-mail templates.

However, when creating/rendering the templates, I don't want the user to have access to any of our API's that manage security and what not. There is use security implications when the user can simply type in C# that will be run within the application itself.

With that said, is there a safe way to render razor templates that prevents the user from accessing any API that the app has? Ideally, this template should have access to System.dll, System.Core.dll and a Models.dll that contains the model that will be used to render the email template. How would I achieve this? Creating a private AppDomain internally in the application?

Comment: Load system dlls and razor dll into a separate app domain and configure its security, policies and restrictions.

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for disaster. Allowing user created code to run on your server makes you liable for what your users type. And even if you separate it out into a seperate app domains, they still can use most of the power of .Net if they want. Look for clever users to use your servers to hack other people's server, launch denial of service attacks, and more.